# How to create a chart like this one in HighCharts?

Tags: highcharts

[image: Graph I need to creat]

How to create a chart like this using HighCharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Value', 'Blend', 'Growth'],
        title: {text: 'Valuation', enabled: true},
        min: 0, // run this 0,1,2 to match our categories
        max: 2,
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },
    yAxis: {
        categories: ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large'],
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        title: {text: 'Market Cap', enabled: true},
        min: 0,
        max: 2
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'US Dow etc',
        data: [[1,2]],
        type: 'scatter'  
    }]
});
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: I tried something similar to this. But I missed startOnTick: false,endOnTick: false I think. Thanks!